# why i am getting object object result from my ajax to php?

Tags: php, json, jquery

here's my jquery:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'function.php',
                type: 'post',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    var toAppend = '';
                    if(typeof data === "object"){
                        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                            toAppend += '<li>'+data[i]["asin"]+'</li>';
                        }
                        $('.results').append(toAppend);
                    }
                }
            });
```

here's my php:

```
echo json_encode($items_from_amazon);
```

I already use the firebug and i get successfully the json values from response but why i am getting object object output?what wrong?am i missing something?

Comment: you get objects if you're using string keys, `e.g json_encode(array('hello' => 'there'))`. javascript arrays have numeric keys. if there's a single string key, you get an object instead.

Comment: don't use string keys? you can't change how JS works.

Comment: yes im using like that? what are the other ways?

Comment: What does `print_r($items_from_amazon)` output?

Comment: [{"asin":{"0":"1433522047"}},{"asin":{"0":"1585161519"}},{"asin":{"0":"1433601729"}},{"asin":{"0":"031043601X"}},{"asin":{"0":"1466227095"}},{"asin":{"0":"B0055ECOUA"}},{"asin":{"0":"1602600155"}},{"asin":{"0":"B0032UYGE6"}},{"asin":{"0":"1604447206"}},{"asin":{"0":"0310443261"}}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i see in your `print_r($items_from_amazon);` output, you have Array-Object-Object, try use this code:

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
 toAppend += '<li>'+data[i]["asin"][0]+'</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo json_encode(array_values($items_from_amazon));
```

This should make sure your JSON will be an array. However, it drops any string keys.

If `$items_from_amazon` is an object, you can cast it to an array:

```
echo json_encode(array_values((array)$items_from_amazon));
```

**EDIT:**
If I misunderstood the question and you want to know why your ASIN elements have objects:

You may want to change the code that generates `$items_from_amazon` so it doesn't append, but assign the ASIN.

```
// This appends
$item['asin'][] = $asin;

// This assigns
$item['asin'] = $asin;

// Note: make sure $asin is a string, not an object or array...
```

You could also use `data[i]["asin"][0]` in client code instead.